# xsl:value-of not working as intended

Tags: xml, xslt

Hey im new to xml and trying to retrieve the value of a phone number shown below.

raw data -

```
 <aboutus>
    <title>The about us page!</title><br/>
    <description>GameChat started in 1934 and was founded by Mr. Gary Cashew who established the business.  
    </description><br/>
    <contact>
        <phone>07642345537</phone><br/>
        <email>GameChat@queries.co.uk </email><br/>
        <post>12 Foxtrot Road, FI23 632</post><br/>
    </contact>
</aboutus>
```

Template trying to turn data into a table

```
<table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Information</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="phone"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

When used my table is created but the value of phone is not entered. I've probably made an amateur mistake so any help would be greatful, thanks

all of my xlst code looks like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>

        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Information</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Phone</td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
            </td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you post your input XML and complete XSLT?

Comment: @LingamurthyCS, It was there just not formatted correctly.

Comment: without knowing what the 'current node' is here in this context, we hav e no way of knowing if select="phone" is correct. For instance it would be valid if it was part of a <template match="//contact">

Comment: the `<xsl:value-of` will be relative to the xml node you are on. So if this is not in a template that is positioned at the `<contact>` node  or perhaps looping through the contact children nodes, it will not find anything. What is the context you are using this in?. If just wanted a global - find the phone node, try `//phone`. Please post more of the XSLT so we can see the context

Comment: Yes, Robbert. I was also looking for the complete XSLT. By just a snippet, won't know the current node it is working on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<xsl:value-of select="/aboutus/contact/phone" />
```

as your template matches the root node, the context is positioned at the `<aboutus>` node, you need to get the path to `<phone>` correct as per the hierarchy (This is assuming that is all the XML and `<aboutus>` is the root node)

or

Don't care about the hierarchy and just want to select the `<phone>` tag whereever it is (assuming there is only one) try

```
<xsl:value-of select="//phone" />
```

Comment: Tried both but unfortunately didnt work. thanks though

Comment: Granted I just edited the first one (wasn't quite right). But I have tested both of these given your sample XML and XSLT and both work, so there must be more to your issue. How do you establish that it doesn't work out of interest

Comment: ah i have no idea then :(

Comment: @lc535 - For your review check [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=ba38ace5-aa70-4adb-ba6d-27a33a1ff2ef-xsltransformation) (click the transform XML with XSL button) and [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation/?save=f8d517de-c1d9-4d6e-9400-3ee2e49192f1-xsltransformation)

Comment: strange, i was using a similar website yet opposite results. thanks so much for ur help!

Comment: Do you have a link to the other website, I could try to see what the issue is.